# Inline statement in classes/structs

Tags: c++, inline

Recently, I came across two uses of the `inline`-statement in a header file:

(1)

```
class A {
  public:
    inline A() {
     // ...
    }
};
```

(2)

```
class A {
  public:
    inline A();
};

inline A::A() {
  // ...
}
```

For example (1) I heard that it is good style to use `inline`. Regarding (2) I am not sure if it would change anything if `inline` is used or not.
So, is it good style to use `inline` in either case and would it affect compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case `inline` is not needed since the code is already inlined being defined and declared at the same time as a class member.

Where with `inline` I mean that each translation unit will get its own version of the method which won't interfere with linking.

In the second example without `inline` you will get a linker error since the [one definition rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) is not respected by the translation units: the method is declared inside the class but defined outside, this is not enough for the compiler and you must explicitly specify that each translation unit will get its own copy of the method (that will be in any case optimized later).

Mind that these considerations are not applied to the inline meaning meant as *elision of the method that replaces its invocation at call site with its body directly*, this is a duty of the optimizing compiler which will take care of it, you shouldn't bother hinting it.

Comment: So would you consider (1) as good style? Could you please extend you last statement a little?